# Elisp function select argument from list

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an Elisp function which takes one argument (so far so good). This one argument is supposed to be an item from a list, and nothing else.

Is there a way I can display the list in kind of a "selection buffer" (like dired), where the user can navigate to the item and select it by hitting enter, instead of having to type out the string manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way to do that is via `completing-read`.  You can then use a `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` where you call `minibuffer-completion-help` so as to pop up a `*Completions*` buffer right away, so the user can click on his choice.

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is [`completing-read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Completion.html):

```
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive (list (completing-read ...)))
  ....)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
(defun foo (list)
  (interactive)
  (let ((arg (ido-completing-read "Select from list: " list))))
     ...)
```

The selection process is not like dired, but it is common for emacs users to select from a list using `ido` or other similar alternatives.  You can narrow your search, move between alternatives and a long etc.  Type M-x customize-group RET ido if you want to have a feeling of what preferences you may customize.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use popup-menus for this kind of things:

```
(x-popup-menu 
   (list '(50 50) (selected-frame)) ;; where to popup
   (list "Please choose"            ;; the menu itself
         (cons "" (mapcar (function (lambda (item) (cons item item))) 
                  your-list-of-strings))))
```

BTW, one would like to use `(mapcar 'cons your-list-of-strings your-list-of-strings)` à la Common Lisp, but elisp only takes unary functions in mapcar :-(